# How to store output of os.system() in a variable

Tags: python, os.system

I wrote a small code:

```
import os
os.system('users')
os.system('w')
```

This prints

```
ubuntu
 09:27:25 up 9 days, 21:23,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    42.99.164.66     09:06    5.00s  0.10s  0.00s sh -c w
```

But when i try :

```
import os
from pyslack import SlackClient

user_name = os.system('users')
login_details = os.system('w')

print user_name
print login_details
```

It has the following output:

```
ubuntu
 09:28:32 up 9 days, 21:24,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    42.99.164.66     09:06    0.00s  0.11s  0.00s w
0
0
```

Now i am not sure why i am not able to store the result in the varible , i.e why is it printing 0 ? And what should be the correct way to get rid of it?

Comment: The system() function is the wrong choice in this case. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `os.system` return the exit code of the command.

To capture the output of the command, you can use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
output = subprocess.check_output('users', shell=True)
```

Comment: If the return code is not 0, then `check_output` returns an error.

Answer (score 4):

The value returned by the os.system is identical to the return value of the command you launched. Since most calls, like 'users' are written in C, they return 0 when the code is executed successfully ( they have a `return 0;` at the end of the `main()` ).

If you want to save their output, you can redirect their output path (by default `stdout`) to a text file, then read the text file.

```
user_name = os.system('users > users.txt')
login_details = os.system('w > w.txt')

with open("users.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
with open("w.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line

os.system("rm users.txt")
os.system("rm w.txt")
```

I bow to the `subprocess.check_output` solution

Answer (score 3):

From the [os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

`os.system` just execute the command (a string) in a subshell.

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    42.99.164.66     09:06    5.00s  0.10s  0.00s sh -c w
```

Which means the above data is the output written to **stdout** by calling the Standard C function `system()` not **the return value**.

> On Unix, the **return value** is the **exit status** of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the **return value** is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command, given by the Windows environment variable
>   COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always
>   0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit
>   status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell,
>   consult your shell documentation.

So if the exit status is success, `user_name` and `login_details` will get a zero.

As a matter of fact, you can try this:;

```
import subprocess
user = subprocess.check_output(['users'])
details = subprocess.check_output(['w'])

print(user)
print(details)
```

Comment: If i have to get the specific fields out of details , lets say  FROM , i,e the IP it was logged in , how can we achieve that

Comment: @NishantSingh You need `awk` try to run this command `w | awk '{print $3}'` in terminal or you can split the `login_details ` string.